# How to get tess4j to compile in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, dependencies, tesseract, tess4j

So am trying to get the simple ocr test example from the following website
    http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/tutorial/

to correctly compile and read from the .tif image. But for whatever reason I get a bunch of errors when running. I have the folder structure exactly how it is set and followed the instructions, did research on the issue in stackoverflow and downloaded the needed visual redistribution packages from Microsoft Visual c++ 2005,2008,20010,2012,20013 but still a no go. Here is an image of the project structure, code, and errors

http://i59.tinypic.com/t87xp2.png

Comment: Here is the file structure picture as well 
http://i57.tinypic.com/vdjvv8.png

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing Apache Commons IO, which you can get at https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/